# what do the elements of the kth exterior power vector space look like?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know in group theory, when we have a quotient group, the elements are remainders modulo something.  In the context of tensor products and other alien objects, I'm not even sure where to begin trying to understand the object.

The problem with me is that my brain rejects information unless I can know what I am dealing with.  I am unable to just work with definitions without any intuition of what the thing I am working with actually is.  I have a relatively simple problem of finding a basis for an exterior power space and proving that it is a basis, but, to quite frank, I haven't the slightest clue what is going on.

Comment: I sympathize with the cognitive hurdle you face, but the usual "multi-vector" interpretation of an exterior power only gives an interpretation of a _decomposable_ multi-vector; a general element of the exterior power is simply a linear combination of decomposable elements. That said, the wedge product $v_{1} \wedge v_{2}$ may be viewed as the oriented parallelogram spanned by $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$; the wedge product $v_{1} \wedge v_{2} \wedge v_{3}$ may be viewed as the oriented parallelepiped spanned by $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, and $v_{3}$; and so on.